# How would map DLCs affect me joining a game?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In the Assassin's Creed multiplayer series, how would map DLCs affect my joining an online game?

I can think of 3 possibilities:

1. I get kicked out if the match changes to a DLC-only map.
2. I cannot join matches hosted by DLC players, even if they are playing a non-DLC map currently.
3. I can join a match that rotates to DLC-only maps, but matches started by myself won't be able to rotate to those maps.

Being difficult enough as it is to find games to join, it would be irritating if map DLCs just reduce that selection because matches are hosted by DLC purchasers.

Answer (score 1):

The way it worked in the previous AC game is that if you had DLC maps installed, you could specify to turn it on or off in the settings. If people wanted to join a party, they had to make sure all the DLC they don't share is set to off.
I assume this will be the case here - depending on who started the game, joining players must have all DLC he specified as on.

Comment: That seems to tilt the matches in favor of DLC maps, doesn't it?